# Angular app not displaying $scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to setup a basic angular app to test some translation logic and somehow I can't get my data to display on the frontend.

Here's my html:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p >{{ title }}</p>
    <p >{{ text }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    title: 'PAGE_TITLE',
    text :'some random page text'
  };
});
```

I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/PZpgzv), added reset.css, jQuery and AngularJS as depedencies, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It should be `{{data.title}}` & ``{{data.text}}``

Comment: ugh. thx a lot, write it up as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: i added an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind those property from `data` object as `title` and `text` belongs to that `data` object.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p >{{ data.title }}</p>
    <p >{{ data.text }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always need to write the scope object whose property you need to print.

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p >{{ data.title }}</p>
    <p >{{ data.text }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try like this.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `{{data.title}}` & `{{data.text}}`